# preparedStatement syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I recently encountered this problem with Java PreparedStatements. I have the following code:

```
String selectSql1
        = "SELECT `value` FROM `sampling_numbers` WHERE `value` < (?)" ;
    ResultSet rs1 = con.select1(selectSql1,randNum);
```

where the `select1` method is

```
    public ResultSet select1(String sql, int randNum) {
    try {
        this.stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, randNum);
        return this.stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, it keeps throwing this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2777)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651)
    at util.P_DBCon.select1(P_DBCon.java:59)
    at app.RandomNumberGenerator.main(RandomNumberGenerator.java:60)

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at app.RandomNumberGenerator.main(RandomNumberGenerator.java:64)
```

This problem does not happen when I do the naive way of doing "...`value < " + randNum` but I would like to do so this way.

Any help is much appreciated.

### UPDATE

I tried with the various recommendations by the community, like

```
String selectSql1
        = "SELECT `value` FROM `sampling_numbers` WHERE value < ?" ;

String selectSql1
        = "SELECT value FROM sampling_numbers WHERE value < ?" ;
```

and still the error message comes out.

Comment: can u just take off all ` form  your sql string and also brackets around ? May be like this: selectSql1
        = "SELECT value FROM sampling_numbers WHERE value < ?"

Comment: why do you use brackets around ?

Comment: @JunedAhsan i tried your variation, still gives errors.

Comment: @JunedAhsan: Parenthesis around placeholder `?` is not an error. It seems OP is posting error from somewhere else.

Comment: @bryansis2010 on your update 2nd SQL string should work, clean your project and build again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The solution to your problem is actually very easy, you are calling [Statement.executeQuery(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) when you want to call [PreparedStatement.executeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) -

```
this.stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql); // Prepares the Statement.
stmt.setInt(1, randNum);               // Binds the parameter.
// return this.stmt.executeQuery(sql); // calls Statement#executeQuery
return this.stmt.executeQuery();       // calls your set-up PreparedStatement
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ResultSet select1(String sql, int randNum) {
    try {
        this.stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, randNum);
        return this.stmt.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

for reference see below code

```
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT EMP_ID,EMP_PWD FROM employee " +
                    "WHERE EMP_ID = '"+param1+"'");
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
```