# I am trying to insert records in mysql table from java and keep getting error message

Tags: java, mysql

```
private static void insertData(Connection conn) throws SQLException {

      String insertsql = "INSERT INTO ng_users(username, password) VALUES (?,?)";
      PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(insertsql);

      for(int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++)
      {
          String[] data= temps.get(i).trim().split(Pattern.quote("|"));
          ps.setString(1, data[0].toString());
          ps.setString(2, data[1].toString());
          ps.executeUpdate(insertsql);     
      }   
}
```

error msg:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)'"

Comment: I would debug that for-loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [preparedStatement syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420038/preparedstatement-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1):

The method [`executeUpdate(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) is inherited from [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) and directly executes the given SQL.

Instead you should call [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()), which will execute the SQL given at construction ([`Connection#prepareStatement(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String))), and more important, consider the arguments passed to it via [`setString(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)).